# Questions seeking illicit help from EL&U community on exams, etc

Tags: feature-request

I have never yet flagged a question, but wanted to flag https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178675/why-is-it-important-to-read-dystopian-texts when it became evident that the questioner was asking us to help him or her with an exam answer, and probably intending to pass our community’s insight off as his or her own. I was surprised to find that the menu of options (reasons) for flagging a question did not really allow for this as an objection to a question. Perhaps it should.

Comment: 'Other' is always an option where you can explain your reason.

Comment: Some don't want to participate in a student's quest for an easy answer (and others don't mind if there's a good question in it). This, to me, is a useful [guide](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/333/how-to-deal-with-homework-questions) (though unofficial). Flagging doesn't really do anything but require a mod's attention. Closing, down voting, and commenting are all options.

Comment: What's illicit about asking for help? Most language exams are useless anyway. I've always found that if you wanted people to have a particular answer on an exam question, you should tell them what it is before the exam.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, a close vote would have been more appropriate. The question has since been voted closed as Primarily Opinion-Based by five other users which I think is the best action for this post.